# MOSFET won’t turn-off at low drain current

Tags: mosfet, bjt

I am trying to design a MOSFET driver circuit for a bi-directional DC/DC converter. The load current is about 17A rms Max. Max input voltage will be about 54V DC. The image below is not the whole circuit obviously, just the driver for highside PMOS.

I am not using a bootstrap circuit and NMOS/driver because in some situations I would like the MOSFET to be permanently on.

Now it is not really a problem but when my load current falls below about 2A, the load voltage wont go all the way down to 0V anymore. My guese is due to drain-source capacitance, but I really have no idea. Anyone that can explain this phenomenon to me?

Here is my circuit:

[image: PMOS switching circuit]

This is the output current and voltage for a large load (R8=5.86 Ohm):
[image: MOSFET output current/voltage for a large load]

Input signal (V4) and MOSFET output voltage for a large load (R8=5.86 Ohm):
[image: Input signal (V4) and MOSFET output voltage for a large load]

This is the MOSFET switching voltage and current for R8=5.86 Ohm:
[image: Mosfet switching voltage and current for a large load (R8=5.86 Ohm]

Vgs for R8=5.86 Ohm:
[image: Vgs for large load]

This is the output current and voltage for a small load (R8=1k Ohm):
[image: MOSFET output current/voltage for a small load]

The MOSFET switching voltage and current for R8=1k Ohm.
[image: MOSFET switching voltage/current small load]

Vgs for R8=1k Ohm:
[image: Vgs for R8=1k Ohm]

I uploaded the LTspice circuit [here](https://mega.nz/file/H3BnSYAA#td7LNlZclhWudyusGoqfMNE2QTWvZZ406GgCkl6eopU).

Comment: What is the FET gate voltage when you see this problem? How much leakage current are you seeing?

Comment: @ThePhoton Gate voltage is switched between about 54V and 36V for about -18V of Vgs. Leakage current I have no idea, would have to check tonight/tomorrow when I am back at the computer.

Comment: Well, you have a circuit that should deliver 18 volts to where the zener is even if unfitted so, maybe the zener was an afterthought and maybe the resistor values were an afterthought after... an initial problem that may have damaged your MOSFETs?

Comment: @Andyaka It is just a simulation, I have yet to build the circuit.

Comment: OK, then be clear about the load connected, the current and the voltage seen.

Comment: @Andyaka You are right. I will show a couple of scope images tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply seeing the RC time constant of various direct and effective capacitances discharged slowly through a quite high load resistance.  Your test repeats before this discharge can even complete.